# mainline utility for updating kernel is not working

Tags: kernel, updates, 22.04

I am trying to update kernel version to latest kernel with mainline utility on Ubuntu 22.04.3. However my mainline utility is not listing kernels for update. It only lists already installed kernels, how can I fix it?

```
$ sudo mainline list
mainline 1.4.8
Updating Kernels...
FAILED
!!! kernel_list empty!
----------------------------------------------------------------
Available Kernels
----------------------------------------------------------------
5.15.0-86.96    Running    
5.15.0.86.83    Installed  
5.5.2-050502.202002041931    Installed  
5.4.0-164.181    Installed  
5.4.0-163.180    Installed  
5.4.0-162.179    Installed  
5.4.0-159.176    Installed  
5.4.0-156.173    Installed
```

Comment: If your utility uses the [Ubuntu Mainline PPA](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/?C=N;O=D), please be aware that [others](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490640&page=2&p=14161267#post14161267) noted that it seemed to be offline around the time of you posted your question.

Comment: You are right; that was the problem. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

The mainline utility was not working as [Ubuntu Mainline PPA](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/?C=N;O=D) was offline.
Its working now

```
$ sudo mainline list
mainline 1.4.8
Updating Kernels...
----------------------------------------------------------------      
Available Kernels
----------------------------------------------------------------
6.5.7                      
6.5.6                      
6.5.5
```